# Files are getting corrupted when download using ftp in java

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer

Files are getting corrupted when I am trying to pull a compressed files. Here is the code I have used. I am not able to understand what I am going wrong. The format of files is .zip and inside it has XML files. After downloading it from remote server,XML files tags are changed and looks corrupted.

```
public Boolean pullConfirmationsFTP(String host, String sftpUserName, String sftpPwd,
      String sftpPort, String fromConfirmationDirectory, String archiveConfirmationDirectory,
      String toDirectory) {
    try {

      // new ftp client
      FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
      // try to connect
      ftp.connect(host);
      // login to server
      if (!ftp.login(sftpUserName, sftpPwd)) {
        ftp.logout();
        LOG4J.error("Authentication failed");
      }
      int reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
      // FTPReply stores a set of constants for FTP reply codes.
      if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
        ftp.disconnect();
      }

      // enter passive mode
      ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

      // get system name
      // System.out.println("Remote system is " + ftp.getSystemType());
      // change current directory
      ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(fromConfirmationDirectory);
      System.out.println("Current directory is " + ftp.printWorkingDirectory());

      // get list of filenames
      FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles();

      if (ftpFiles != null && ftpFiles.length > 0) {
        // loop thru files
        for (FTPFile file : ftpFiles) {
          try{
          if (!file.isFile()) {
            continue;
          }
          LOG4J.error("File is " + file.getName());
          // get output stream
          OutputStream output;
          output = new FileOutputStream(toDirectory + file.getName());
          // get the file from the remote system
          ftp.retrieveFile(file.getName(), output);

          // close output stream
          output.close();

          // delete the file
          ftp.deleteFile(file.getName());
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
            LOG4J.error("Error in pushing file : ",e);
          }
        }
      }

      ftp.logout();
      ftp.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      LOG4J.error(ex);
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't say which FTPClient you use, but I'm guessing it is from apache commons.
Documentation for [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) says:

> The default settings for FTPClient are for it to use FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE , FTP.NON_PRINT_TEXT_FORMAT , FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE , and FTP.FILE_STRUCTURE . The only file types directly supported are FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE and FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE

As the zip-file is a binary file you have to add

```
ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

API: [FTPClient.setFileType](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType%28int%29)