# How can i get pdf files from FTP server as base64 encoding format on Java spring mvc project?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, encoding, base64

I'm trying getting files from FTP server on Java spring mvc project. I'm study on windows but my tomcat server is in linux machine. Following code returns base64 encoding files and created base64 url for front end side and this files temporarily held. This code works fine windows but works bad on linux machine. Getting pdf files are issueless in windows, corrupted in linux machine. Works differently according to file size.

This result in linux machine, this file is issueless in folder of FTP.
[image]

This result on windows machine

[image]

Can the problem be caused by base64 encoding?

```
public List<String> getMultipleBase64PDF(String workingDir) {
    List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles(workingDir);
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                fileNames.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
        if (fileNames.size() > 0) {
            for (String filename : fileNames) {
                String encodedFile = "";
                InputStream is = client.retrieveFileStream( workingDir);
                File file = File.createTempFile("tmp", null);
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(is, file); 
                byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                bis.read(bytes, 0, (int) file.length());
                bis.close();
                encodedFile += new String(Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encode(bytes), "UTF-8");
                fileList.add(encodedFile);
                file.delete();
                client.completePendingCommand();
            }
        }
        disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

Comment: For testing purposes: did you try to load the PDF generated on the Windows machine into Linux and opening it there to see if the result is the same? (exclude PDF viewer error).

Comment: Yes i try this but in the linux machine results are same.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990280/ftp-file-corrupt-after-download-with-apache-commons-net the default transfer mode is ASCII, you need to switch to binary

Comment: If the working Windows file is corrupt on the Linux machine than either the Windows PDF isn't so strict about errors, or the the Linux PDF viewer is not working properly (there are many different PDF versions, make sure you have support to open them). Did you check the PDF generated on the Linux machine in Windows to see if that works? (just to rule out the issue is not caused by the generator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTPClient is set to ASCII by default. While configuring FTPClient bean, try switching your client from using ASCII to binary, like so:

```
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

[Here's the original answer for the similair problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710611/files-are-getting-corrupted-when-download-using-ftp-in-java)

Comment: Thank you very much!